# Yii2: How to display search result without gridview in Yii2

Tags: php, search, gridview, yii2

Trying to implement search box for my page in which user has to enter job_code to get its order status. I'm getting result but this result in grid view I don't want this grid view. So, that I can place various attributes on page at different positions.

**Search form In which user has to enter job_code**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => ['tracking'],'method' => 'get','class'=>'lockscreen-credentials']); ?>
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'job_code')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Job Code..'))->label(false); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat']) ?>
<?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat']) ?> 
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

[image]

**Result Page on which Search Result will display**

```
<body class="lockscreen">
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'job_code',
            'client_code',
            'company_name',
            'job_description:ntext',
            'status',
            'emp_email:email',
            'emp_mobile',
            'emp_first_name',
            'emp_last_name',  
        ],
    ]); ?>      
</body>
```

[image]

**Controllers**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new Status();
        $searchModel = new StatusSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionTracking()
    {
         $model = new Status();
         $searchModel = new StatusSearch();
         $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('tracking', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Saurabh, Your question is not much clear. Could you explain better what you need?

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge,
actually i'm creating search page for client so that he can see his job status. client has to enter his job_id to get status. its just like amazon order tracking system where buyer enters his order id to know its current order status.

Comment: when i put job_code in search box its showing result but in grid view, i dont want that grid view.

Comment: i have updated the question with images

Comment: Two things. 1 ) show your controller for this action. 2 ) How would you view the search result ?

Comment: in search result page there is gridview, I dont want that grid view, I need only attributes like job_code, client_code and so on

Comment: From your image i see you want only an horizontal row with result.Ok?

Comment: Well show the controller code for the seach action and i thing i can help you. Or at least I hope so.

Comment: no i dont want horizontal row results, i need only dump result, i want to place attributes at different postions on pages like company_name result should appear on top saying e.g Welcome,company_name;

Comment: Give me  two hour. i must go out...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83618/discussion-between-saurabh-and-scaisedge).

Comment: I have post an answer.  I hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the data provider models data in this way

*for a dump result you don't need  to format your code with html and limit the  view to the first (or the only) line of data available. 
Then for sample i use use only `echo`*

```
<body class="lockscreen">
   <?php 

     echo 'job_code = ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->job_code .' - ' ;
     echo 'client_code = ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->client_code .' - ';
     echo 'company_name = ' .  $dataProvider->models[0]->company_name .' - ';
     echo 'job_description = ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->job_description .' - ';
     echo 'status = ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->status .' - ';
     // and so on  



</body>
```

I you need to show more then a row of data, you must obviously loop for all the models you prefer

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ''job_code'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

-- Getting this error

Comment: I have update the answer. I hope there aren't other mistake. I' writing without testing the code.

Comment: I have tried this and in my case i am getting data using `SqlDataProvider` then i need to use array instaed of object to get the final value.
like here `$dataProvider->models[0]['job_code']`

Comment: @always-a-learner  if you have an array of arrays  instead of an array of object the you could  accessi by key this way  `$dataProvider->models[0]['company_name']` or $yourArray[yourIndex]['company_name']